# Wp query and ACF isnt functioning

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have tried and tried and tired and tried.

I cannot get my WPquery with ACF to work WHY!? it seems so simple

```
$PostTypeChoice = get_field('post_type_single_pg');
$categoryTag1 = get_field('taxonomy_single_pg');
$categoryTagTerm1 = get_field('taxonomy_term_single_pg');

$args = array(
    'post_type' => $PostTypeChoice,
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => $categoryTag1,
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array_values($categoryTagTerm1),
        ),
    ),
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);

if ($query->have_posts()) :
    while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
?>
    <div class="post-item">
        <!-- Display your post content here -->
        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <div class="post-content">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
    endwhile;
else :
    echo 'No posts found.';
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

it load nothing and doesn't even give me "No posts found."

it is how ive set up the data from ACF? should it retrieve "object" or
"name"

its driving me insane!!!

what an i doing wrong!!!

Comment: If "have_posts" is true for the query, you should see posts, else you should see your "No posts found."  message. The fact that you don't see anything makes me suspect some sort of fatal error above the line with the if statement.

Do you have any debugging enabled? Otherwise, can you log the individual variables to the screen to check what $args actually is made up of?

Comment: What are you getting from your ACF fields? `var_dump` each one of your variables that you are assigning to `get_field()` and see if you are getting any data. That's where I would start.